# Sql Select Where In doesn't work properly

Tags: php, sql

I want to run a following sql query in my php code:`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (5,6)`where the ids inside brackets should be variables content. This query executes properly when I try it on `phpmyadmin`, however it returns only 1 element when I execute it using this code:

```
$pdo = new ConnectionDatabase();
$db = $pdo->connect();
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (:ids)");
$ids = "";
foreach($this->getIds() as $matId)
{
    $ids .= $matId . ",";
}
$ids = substr_replace($ids, "", -1);
$query->bindParam(':ids', $ids);
$query->execute();
$response = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The `$ids` is equal "5,6" and the query seems to be created successfully. Why does it happen?

Comment: Because  `"5,6"` is a __string__.

Comment: do this `$instr = "(".implode(",",$this->getIds()).")"`, thats the "in" string, values wrapped on () and separated by a comma

Comment: @FranciscoHahn Thanks, I got it.